# Tell if a specific function is called with Python AST

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a Python AST, is it possible to tell if a specific function is being called regardless of the function's name?

In Python, I could do the following:

```py
def identity(x):
    return x

def print_id(func):
    print(hash(func))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(hash(identity))

    x = identity
    print(hash(x))

    print_id(identity)
```

Which I would be able to use to tell whether the function is being called. From the AST module, I can use `visit_Call` to check whether a function of the same *name* is being called, but this quickly falls apart if the function is aliased or imported under a different name.

```py
class Visitor(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.calls = []

    def visit_Call(self, node: ast.Call) -> "Any":
        if isinstance(node.func, ast.Name):
            if node.func.id == "identity":
                self.calls.append(node)
                print("found identity call")
        return self.generic_visit(node)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to statically determine this.

As you point out, at run time the scope could bind that function name in a manner you can't easily determine form the AST (ie, without running it).  Consider this example:

```py
def func1():
    print("func1")

def func2():
    print("func2")

func2 = func1
func2()
```

The AST's `node.func.id` will be `func2`, but at runtime, `func1` gets called.

The difficultly in determining this statically should be clear with this modification:

```py
if complex_runtime_condition:
    func2 = func1
func2()
```

Comment: I think you're right about it being hard to statically analyse. It can't be *impossible* to determine otherwise tools like flake8 wouldn't be able to identify Syntax Errors without running the code.

I agree that it's probably too hard to answer in a StackOverflow question though since it will require properly parsing the Python AST :D.